# final recursive method and a functional method

Tags: java

I've been having problems in solving this :

Given 2 strings of characters A and B of the same length, which satisfy that they are equal character by character up to a certain position and different character by character starting from said position, determine the first position in which A and B are different. By Example A = "buenosdiaspepe" and B = "buenosdiasjuan", would return position 10.

I've been trying to do it with a final recursive method and a functional method and can't seem to get it right.

Could anyone please help me with these two methods? Thanks

```
public static Integer recursiva (String secuencia1, String secuencia2) {
        int a=0;
        int posicion1= secuencia1.length()/2;
        int posicion2= secuencia2.length()/2;
        int posicionfinal= posicion1 + posicion2; 
        if(secuencia1.charAt(posicion1)==secuencia2.charAt(posicion1)) {
            a=1;
            return posicionfinal;
        } else{
            return a;
        }
```

That's what I have, I'm new in Java and Data Structures (Im new in programming) , and I dont know how to keep going with this code.

Comment: We love that you're here with us and we need to see your code so we can help you fix is. We won't write it for you.

Comment: What have you tried? If you update your question to contain the code you have so far people can help you improve it :)

Comment: Why recursive? `for(int i=0;i<secuencia1.length;i++)if(secuencia1.charAt(i)!=secuencia2.charAt(i))return i;return -1;` could do the task otherwise. (The `return -1;` runs after the loop, when no differences found)